# Data not getting pushed in main schema array mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to push child schema data to user schema but it is not getting pushed inside an array defined in parent schema.

This is my **child controller** code :-

```
userr.save((err, doc) =>{

        if(!err){
            if(req.userData.role2 === 'admin') {
            console.log("saving successful");
            res.send(doc);
            Admin.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.userData.userId },{ 'admin.admins' : { $push: { users: userr }}},
              function (error, success) {
                if (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                }
                console.log(success);
              });
        }             
        }
```

**Parent schema :-**

```
var adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company  name can't be empty.",
                required: false
                },  
    companyID:  {
                type: String,
                },              
    address :   {
                type: String,
                required: "Address can't be empty.",
                },
    contactDetails : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company contact number can't be empty.",
                },
    admins:     {
                        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                        email :     {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Email can't be empty.",
                                    unique: true
                                    },
                        password:   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Password name can't be empty."
                                    },
                        firstName : {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "First name can't be empty."
                                    },
                        lastName : {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Last name can't be empty."
                                    },  
                        phoneNumber :   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Reqired for further contact. Can't be empty."
                                    },
                        designation :   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Designation can't be empty."
                                    },
                        verified: String,                               
                        role: String,
                        emailResetTokenn: String,
                        emailExpires: Date,
                        saltSecret: String,//this is user for encryption and decryption of password 
                        users:[ {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Userr'}]   
    }           
});
mongoose.model('Admin', adminSchema);
```

So I want to push data inside `users` array. Here `Userr` is child schema name `mongoose.model('Userr' , userrSchema);`.

I can see a new child object is been created on a new collection but not getting pushed on Parent `Admin` schema. What should I do to make changes ?

**EDIT:-**

This is my parent schema controller:-

```
var admin = new Admin();
    admin.companyName = req.body.companyName;
    admin.address = req.body.address;
    admin.contactDetails  = req.body.contactDetails;
    admin.admins = {
                    email : req.body.email,
                    password: req.body.password, 
                    firstName : req.body.firstName, 
                    lastName : req.body.lastName,
                    phoneNumber : req.body.phoneNumber,
                    designation : req.body.designation,
                    role : "admin",
                    verified :"false",
                    users : [] 
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is here: `{ 'admin.admins' : { $push: { users: userr } } }`. You reference to the field 'admin.admins' but it doesn't exist, it's just 'admins' and I think the syntax isn't correct, too. Also I'm not sure if Mongoose will set it well by passing the entire object but what you really want to insert is the user ID so I think your code should be:

```
Admin.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.userData.userId }, { $push: { 'admins.users': userr._id } }, function (error, success) {
    //...
});
```

Comment: No , I have mentioned my parent schema controller in my EDIT . That's why I have written `{ 'admin.admins' : { $push: { users: userr } } }`. But I want to push entire object of child ie; `doc` ?

Comment: In your schema definition, users are an array of ObjectId, so you want to push an id, not a document. And you don't have to point `admin' because `Admin.findOneAndUpdate` is already a query on `admin` collection.

Comment: Suppose if I change it to `users:[ userrSchema ]`. Then ? What changes should I make to pass child schema in the array.

Comment: You shouldn't change your schema, just store the ID and populate the user data at the `find` queries if you need it

Comment: Sorry I am new in this , so I didn't get how will I populate the entire user data at the find ? I need all the data from the child schema. Should I have to mention all the keys on array ?

Comment: Check the official documentation at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html but the summary is that you could do something like this: `Admin.findById(adminId).populate('user').exec(function(err, admin){ console.log(admin.user) });` where admin.user will contain the populated user data

Comment: So you mean to say I will use two condition over here ? First to `Admin.findById` then again `Admin.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.userData.userId }` push ? Little confuse

Comment: Well, we're talking about two different things. On the one hand, in my answer you have the code with which you can insert a user in the array (test it and let me know if now you can insert elements in the array). On the other hand, if you call to database to retrieve the admins and want all user data you must use the populate statement as I said in my comment. If you want to mix both processes, I think you can do it with `Admin.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.userData.userId }, { $push: { 'admins.users': userr._id } }).populate('user').exec(function(error, success){});`

Comment: Its not working .Still passing just `Id` . You mean `.populate('userr')` ?

Comment: Excuse me, it should be `populate('admins.users')`, the path to the ObjectIds you want to populate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194589/discussion-between-noobcoder-and-virgiliogm).